# Why PHP is not installing in my Ubuntu server and how can I install it now?

Tags: ubuntu, php, php5

Everytime when I try to install php using this command, it shows me "E: Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate".

Here is the command below what I used for installing php-

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you are using an old version of Ubuntu that is no longer supported or you are following a tutorial that is outdated. Php and by extension php-mcrypt are now at version 7.

```
sudo apt-get install ... php7.0-mcrypt
```

Comment: I have just tried your command and now it is showing me "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package
." . What does that mean?